# How to avoid black border/background, i.e. no transparency, on albert?

Tags: albert

I'm observing some weird behavior where there is a large black box behind albert. albert should just consist of the rounded rectangular shaped field in the middle of that black box - the black box shouldn't be there. It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you don't have hardware graphics acceleration enabled or you are missing a [compositor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager) for the transparency to work. These problems are not related to albert, but are a general desktop misconfiguration. Google will help you to solve it. If there are other reasons for this symptom, please let me know.

If your are using a standalone window manager that does not come with a compositor shipped (e.g. i3wm, openbox, …) install a standalone compositor like compton and make sure it's running.

<sub>Note: I am the author of this app. This Q&A is part of the migration of the FAQ to the public.</sub>